# Temporary value dropped while borrowed while pushing elements into a Vec

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to solve the [RPN calculator](https://exercism.org/tracks/rust/exercises/rpn-calculator) exercise at exercism but stumbled upon this `temporary value dropped while borrowed` error that I can't seem to work out.

Here's my code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum CalculatorInput {
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
    Value(i32),
}

pub fn evaluate(inputs: &[CalculatorInput]) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut stack = Vec::new();

    for input in inputs {
        match input {
            CalculatorInput::Value(value) => {
                stack.push(value);
            },
            operator => {
                if stack.len() < 2 {
                    return None;
                }
                let second = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let first = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let result = match operator {
                  CalculatorInput::Add => first + second,
                  CalculatorInput::Subtract => first - second,
                  CalculatorInput::Multiply => first * second,
                  CalculatorInput::Divide => first / second,
                  CalculatorInput::Value(_) => return None,
                };
                stack.push(&result.clone());
            }
        }
    }
    if stack.len() != 1 {
        None
    } else {
        Some(*stack.pop().unwrap())
    }
}
```

And the error I get:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:32:29
   |
32 |                 stack.push(&result.clone());
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                             |
   |                             creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
36 |     if stack.len() != 1 {
   |        ----- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

If I understand correctly, the variable `result` is no loger live outside of the for loop (outside of the operator match branch indeed), that's why I cloned it, but it still gives me the same error.

How can I make a copy of the result which is owned by the stack Vec (if that's what I should do)?

---

Just for reference, and in case anybody fins this useful, this is the final solution taking into account all the help received:

```rust
use crate::CalculatorInput::{Add,Subtract,Multiply,Divide,Value};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum CalculatorInput {
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
    Value(i32),
}

pub fn evaluate(inputs: &[CalculatorInput]) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut stack: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    for input in inputs {
        match input {
            Value(value) => {
                stack.push(*value);
            },
            operator => {
                if stack.len() < 2 {
                    return None;
                }
                let second: i32 = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let first: i32 = stack.pop().unwrap();

                let result: i32 = match operator {
                  Add => first + second,
                  Subtract => first - second,
                  Multiply => first * second,
                  Divide => first / second,
                  Value(_) => return None,
                };
                stack.push(result);
            }
        }
    }
    if stack.len() != 1 {
        None
    } else {
        stack.pop()
    }
}
```

No need to clone, because i32 implements the Copy trait.

The problem was that my vec was receiving an `&i32` instead of `i32`, and thus rust infered it to be a `Vec<&i32>`.

Comment: I recommend you to explicit type your stack `let mut stack : Vec<i32> = Vec::new();` and then fix error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, I typed it and saw that in fact stack was a `Vec<&i32>`

Comment: Be careful of operator precedence: `&result.clone()` is equivalent to `&(result.clone())` which means that you are taking the reference of the newly cloned value, without it being bound to anything, therefore making it a temporary. `Vector::push` takes its argument by value, meaning the reference to the temporary value is moved into the vector. But after that line, the temporary is freed, so the reference doesn't point to anything. @Stargateur's advice is sound here because it would have showed you that you were trying to push a `&i32` into a `Vec<i32>`.

Comment: Great comment @SirDarius, that's the kind of explanation I was looking for, even though I still have to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because Rust did not infer the type you expected.

In your code, the type of `value` is inferred to be `&i32` because `input` is a reference of a element in `inputs`, and you `push` a `value` later, therefore the type of `stack` is inferred to be `Vec<&i32>`.

A best fix is to explicitly specify the type of stack:

```rust
let mut stack: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
```

And because `i32` has implemented `Copy` trait, you should never need to clone a `i32` value, if it is a reference, just dereference it.

Fixed code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum CalculatorInput {
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
    Value(i32),
}

pub fn evaluate(inputs: &[CalculatorInput]) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut stack: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    for input in inputs {
        match input {
            CalculatorInput::Value(value) => {
                stack.push(*value);
            }
            operator => {
                if stack.len() < 2 {
                    return None;
                }
                let second = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let first = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let result = match operator {
                    CalculatorInput::Add => first + second,
                    CalculatorInput::Subtract => first - second,
                    CalculatorInput::Multiply => first * second,
                    CalculatorInput::Divide => first / second,
                    CalculatorInput::Value(_) => return None,
                };
                stack.push(result);
            }
        }
    }
    if stack.len() != 1 {
        None
    } else {
        Some(stack.pop().unwrap())
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw other's people solution and just realized that there was no need to clone. I was wondering if it was because of the Copy trait, and you jurs confirmed it. I'm not so lost after all!

Comment: For reference, you could also write `let mut stack = Vec::<i32>::new()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same behavior with this simple exemple

```
fn main() {
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    
    let a = String::from("test");
    stack.push(&a.clone());
    //-------- ^

    println!("{:?}", stack);
}
```

and the good way is to not borrow when clone.

```
fn main() {
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    
    let a = String::from("test");
    stack.push(a.clone());
    //-------- ^
    
    println!("{:?}", stack);
}
```

The variable should be used like this `stack.push(result.clone());` and change code like this

```
pub fn evaluate(inputs: &[CalculatorInput]) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut stack: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    //---------------- ^
    for input in inputs {
        match input {
            CalculatorInput::Value(value) => {
                stack.push(value.clone());
               //----------------- ^
            },
            operator => {
                if stack.len() < 2 {
                    return None;
                }
                let second = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let first = stack.pop().unwrap();
                let result = match operator {
                  CalculatorInput::Add => first + second,
                  CalculatorInput::Subtract => first - second,
                  CalculatorInput::Multiply => first * second,
                  CalculatorInput::Divide => first / second,
                  CalculatorInput::Value(_) => return None,
                };
                
                stack.push(result.clone());
                        //-^
            }
        }
    }
    if stack.len() != 1 {
        None
    } else {
        Some(stack.pop().unwrap())
    //------- ^
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just figuring this out when I saw your answer.
Instead of `stack.push(value.clone())` I did `stack.push(*value);` and it works, not sure why though. Shouldn't `*value` also be invalid outside of the match?

Comment: @opensas It's valid because i32 is a `Copy` type (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/marker/trait.Copy.html). This means that instead of being moved into the vector, it is a trivial bitwise copy.